# Can not connect to VirtualHost when VPN

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, vpn, routing

I run VirtualBox on my local machine with Ubuntu which hosts my application. Application URLs points to VM IP Address in my hosts file (`/etc/hosts`). And this configuration works fine. I can also ssh from console to VM using VM IP Address .

But when I run VPN I loose connection to my VPN. Application URLs do not work. I can not ssh to VM IP Address.

I would like to work remotely with my colleagues, and now it is impossible.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you please post your routing table, when on/off the VPN?

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this?